# Removing a value from a string with delimiters

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing a cart system, when a client select various items the data is sent as string with IDs and comma as delimiter, example: `1,2,3`

I save that to the database and I can show each item description using a custom function and foreach. The problem is if a client want to remove a item, how should I proceed to update the new changes to the DB? Because I tried with str_replace and I can only remove the ID but keeps the delimiter (comma), example: `1,2,` or `1,,3`

Any ideas or suggestions how can I improve this? Thank you for your time.

Regards.

Comment: Normalise your database. Don't store the cart list as a comma-separated list. Set up a table for it. It'll make querying, updating and reporting much easier.

Comment: Normalize the schema. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Spoiler: Yes it is.).

Comment: You are right, I must normalize the schema.

Comment: Storing delimited lists in a DB is still bad, but if you otherwise needed to do this: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should really normalise the schema, but...

There are many ways to do this. Here's one using using `explode()` and `implode()`.

```
function removeIdFromString(string $str, string$id):string {
    $arr = explode(',',$str);
    if (($key = array_search($id, $arr)) !== false) {
      unset($arr[$key]);
      return implode(',',$arr);
    }
}    


$str = "3,5,7,9";
echo removeIdFromString($str,7);     // 3,5,9


echo removeIdFromString($str,9);     // 3,5,7
```

Good for PHP7+

Demo:https://3v4l.org/qBP9q

Comment: Very interesting function, I will try it, but yes you are right, I really need to normalize the schema.

Comment: Tried, but when I try to remove the 9 the result is 3,5,7, instead of 3,5,7

Comment: My bad - I've posted an alternative version

Comment: The alternative worked perfectly, thank you.